# Hibernate Reverse Engineering with base class

Tags: java, hibernate, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to get Hibernate Tools (and Hibernate 3) to generate my java domain code in the following way:

```
com.example.model.base -> (ex TableBase.java) 
com.example.model -> (ex Table.java)
```

Where TableBase.java is the generated class, and Table extends TableBase.  Also, if Table.java already exists, the regeneration process should not overwrite it.

Since i want to be able to add my own accessor methods to Table.java, and leave the auto-generated TableBase.java in it's own package so i can regenerate at any time.

So far in my searching around I think i need to create my own Reverse Engineering Strategy.  The documentation i've found so far is horrible in this area.  All I really know is that I should create a class that extends DelegatingReverseEngineeringStrategy, and implement tableToMetaAttribute to add the "Base" to the name of my base classes.

Needless to say I haven't had any luck with it so far.  Hope someone can shed some light on this for me!

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere on this?  I'm just trying to figure out how to tell the reveng to give my model classes the proper package name.  The docs are really weak.

Comment: I didn't.  It was too much of a pain. I ended up just going with what Hibernate Tools gave me by default